# Unity AdMob - Banner Ad still not clickable on friends device

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, banner, clickable

The ads are showing on my friends device but still not clickable
what am i doing wrong?

I already manage to add my device as a test device and it is showing a test banner which is correct, but it is still not clickable on any of my friends device but it is showing the ads properly just not clickable

```
 private AdRequest createAdRequest()
{
    return new AdRequest.Builder()
            .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
            .AddTestDevice("42XXXXX384302CFBXXXXX892D4XXXXX1")
            .SetGender(Gender.Female)
            .SetBirthday(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1))
            .TagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)
            .AddExtra("color_bg", "9B30FF")
            .Build();
}
```

Please help the ad request are also counted to my AdMob account but the not clickable thing still bothers me :< what am I possibly doing wrong??

Comment: It seems like this is about the game engine, so please use the `unity3d` tag instead of the `unity` tag, which is for the MS DI framework.

Comment: sorry about that sir

Answer (score 0):

In Unity3D 4.XX your current Assets folder for your game go to

Plugins > Android > AndroidManifest.xml

In the Manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
```

Change it to

```
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
```

My only problem here is the location of the "AndroidManifest.xml" I know what will be change but i cant find the xml file ahahah

"CurrentAssetsFolder" > Plugins > Android > AndroidManifest.xml

You can just also search it in your Unity3D editor "AndroidManifest.xml" together with your scripts etc...